# Compiling Opensmmpbox in Cygwin for windows service

Tags: cygwin, gcc, sms

Need a opensmppbox as a windows service so i try to compile it under cygwin...get this error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lwap
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgwlib
```

okay missing libs. but can't find them in the install. installed all libs via cygwin setup-x86.exe which library am I missing. on kannel.org I also can't find a hint.

Answer (score 0):

okay figured it out with a hint from Pablo: I hade to make and install the kannel first. only copy the kannel libs didn't work.

Comment: compile worked, but do not start in windows...anyone a hint?